# Query based on some data multiple compare

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datatables

Table:

[image]

How do i bring the period when customers have max cc_limit? 
If the cc_limits same for customer for more than one month, take the period with highest year-month data

Comment: show us your expected output in tabular form.

Comment: İ expected 
1 - 19 000,
2 - 12 000,
3 - 16 000,
4 - 12 000

Comment: If the cc limits are equal, for example first cust no 1 and second cust no 1, i should take data with highest yearmonth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `row_number()` window function,Below should work.

```
  select *
     from 
        (select cust_no,year_month,cc_limit,cc_tot_risk,cc_period_risk,cc_ins_risk,
        row_number() over(partition by cust_no order by cc_limit desc) rownum
         from tablename order by cust_no,year_month desc) tab
      where rownum = 1
```

**EDIT :** To clarify why `order by` should be in the inline view.

Scenario : When there are duplicate records for same cc_limit and cust_no,the requirement is to retrieve highest yearmonth record.

**The default order of data retrieval for any table is by the order they are inserted unless a filter caused an index to be used to filter data.**

Suppose 201912 record is inserted first followed by 201911(Not possible  practically though, may be during a database reorganization the order of insertion got flipped) then without `order by` clause would return 201911 record instead of 201912.

```
create table test  (cust_no INT,yearmonth varchar(10),cc_limit INT,
cc_tot_risk INT,cc_period_risk INT,cc_ins_risk INT)
```

# cust_no 1 has 201912 record inserted first and then 201912 and has same cc_limit.

```
insert into test values(1,201911,16000,16,16,0);
insert into test values(2,201912,15000,16,16,0);
insert into test values(1,201912,16000,16,16,0);
insert into test values(3,201912,17000,16,16,0);
insert into test values(4,201911,10000,16,16,0);
```

When the query is executed without `order by` in the inline view,

```
 select *
     from 
        (select cust_no,yearmonth,cc_limit,cc_tot_risk,cc_period_risk,cc_ins_risk,
        row_number() over(partition by cust_no order by cc_limit desc) rownum
         from test) tab
      where rownum = 1
```

The yearmonth returned for cust_no 1 is 201911 instead of 201912

[image]

But the query with `order by` clause would ensure that latest yearmonth record being returned,

```
 select *
         from 
            (select cust_no,year_month,cc_limit,cc_tot_risk,cc_period_risk,cc_ins_risk,
            row_number() over(partition by cust_no order by cc_limit desc) rownum
             from tablename order by cust_no,year_month desc) tab
          where rownum = 1
```

[image]

I have demonstrated the whole behaviour in DBFIDDLE link for MySQL8.0 - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=03b06094d10a0daf7732f0cb19798262

Comment: i take this error-> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Comment: Could you look at the modified query please.

Comment: i take same error,  line -> from cc_datamart order by cust_no,year_month desc) tab

Comment: I ran the query  on mysql 8 and it works perfectly, Look at the query https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=297537a12ab7fd8c11aa8bb95bfa4d0f

Comment: Could you confirm the Database name SQL SERVER, Mysql,oracle etc.? and respective version?

Comment: @zealous - Why should "order by" removed, that should be where it is currently for the query to work when cc_limit is the same to sort by year_month for cust_no and return highest year month data.

Comment: @zealous - The comment you mentioned is for a different scenario. I have updated the answer with detailed explanation of what i meant.Feel free to read and refer the dbfiddle link for demonstration.

Comment: @rhasepy - I still don't understand why order by should throw a syntax error